# Which Launch Image Should I Use?

Tags: iphone

I'm building a game for the iphone, and the main window displays an image in the background describing the game, and I have few other layers of images which are the buttons such as Start New Game, Options and Help.

Should the launch image be only the background image describing the game without the extra image layers or should it be image including the other layers which are Start New Game, Option and Help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bit covering launch  images can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html). Below is an example launch image (left) provided by Apple.

Their docs specifically site concerns about localization, so it's probably best to do without the text and provide an image that just has your background chrome for the view.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I think I'll go with only the background image, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The launch image should give the illusion of a really fast launching of your app. So the better image in your case is an hybrid of your proposal.

You should have the background image describing the game with the extra image layers without the text inside your buttons (Start new game, etc.) If you include the text, the user could think that your app is loaded and would tap on it.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

All the Apple guidelines on launch images are available [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) (scroll down to "Launch Images" section). It seems like the convention is to show buttons but not table view data, based on the examples show and from observing other Apple apps.

It's probably up to you to determine which looks better. I have seen many apps on the app store that totally ignore all of these things you aren't supposed to do:

> - An “application entry experience,” such as a splash screen
> - An About window
> - Branding elements, unless they are a static part of your application’s first screen

So I don't think it's that important for App Store acceptance, but it is very important for user experience.